# Inductive crosstalk mechanism for 2 lines that run parallel on the same layer

Tags: pcb, inductive, coupling, crosstalk

According to Faraday's law, changing magnetic field lines that penetrates the victim line must create voltage on the victim line, but if we imagine, we see lines are orthogonal to the victim trace meaning they penetrate from tom to bottom or vice versa if they are on the same layer and parallel. In this case, induced current must be in a way to decrease penetrating magnetic field lines and must circulate in a circular loop on the victim trace and create eddy currents. Those induced currents circulate, do not travel to other ends along the trace to create change in voltage levels. How come crosstalk occurs in this case? Also, I am trying to connect these ideas to fields that travel between spaces in pcbs, not voltages and currents. Can you help me build intuition?

Answer (score 1):

> How come crosstalk occurs in this case?

Every thing before this sentence is true. These induced voltages will not create a voltage source in series with the trace.

The victim trace is actually victim conducting loop. Magnetic field lines from the aggressor **must penetrate the interior of the loop** not the wire that makes the loop, in order to induce a voltage in series with the loop.

The resulting current will develop voltage at all high resistance points in the series induction path.

This is the primary reason for minimizing the area of all conductive loops in PCB layout.

---

Update:

> do you think displacement currents of aggressor play a role here?

> Also, I am trying to connect these ideas to fields that travel between spaces in pcbs

The aggressor and victim traces form plates of a capacitor. Displacement current exists only while the capacitor is charging or discharging. This is called capacitive coupling. The displacement current couples the current in the aggressor to the current in the victim. For charge to flow, there must be a closed loop. For crosstalk to occur, the loop must include an input.

A copper plane beneath the pair can divert some of the current reducing the crosstalk. This path is parallel to the path to the input victim.

Comment: do you think displacement currents of aggressor play a role here? I mean could they link signal/return loop of the victim and create problems

Comment: Yes. See my answer update.

Answer (score 1):

1. Field lines are circular around the agressor line.
2. Vertical field is stronger on the near side of the victim trace and weaker on the far side.
3. As a result, the victim trace sees a curl component of magnetic field around it which causes an EMF in series with the victim trace.
4. Even if the victim line has infinitesimal width, it would still fall victim to the inductive crosstalk, because it is the field gradient around it that matters.